# Using database class in multiple PHP scripts

Tags: php, database, oop, object, try-catch

I using a DB class (with PDO) for reaching a MySQL server, and i have a question in this regard.

I have a project structure that looks like this:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KA0Y.png)

My problem is that i need in every script create and close the DB object or have another solution for this problem? What is the habit in these cases? Can i somehow generalize the code snippet below?

Right now that's look like this in the affected pages:

```
try
{
    $db = new DB();
} catch (DBException $e)
{
    forwardToErrorPage($e->getMessage());
    return;
}

try
{
    if ($db->someDBFunction($args) == 0)
        header("Location: ../templates/success.php");
    else
        forwardToErrorPage('Adding person failed');
} catch (DBException $e)
{
    forwardToErrorPage($e->getMessage());
}
finally
{
    $db->close();
}
```

Comment: Use includes, even better use classes and [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), see also [DRY priciple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time if you want to use your db you must create a db connection. There are a lot of libraries which help you managing db, but if you want a good and simple approach use a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Another good approach is to do it change your db class into the service and [dependency injection](https://phptherightway.com/#dependency_injection).

I don't want to explain a Singleton pattern, DI and services here because in the internet and on SO there was a lot of instructions for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can include `require_once('/path/to/project/src/DB.php');` in header of all file and in DB.php make your DB handle:

```
try
{
    $db = new DB();
} catch (DBException $e)
{
    forwardToErrorPage($e->getMessage());
    return;
}
```

Better solution which I would recommend to use an ORM like Eloquent ([reference](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/eloquent-illuminate-in-php-without-laravel/)):

```
composer require illuminate/database
```

then in your DB.php file:

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
   "driver" => "mysql",
   "host" =>"127.0.0.1",
   "database" => "acl",
   "username" => "root",
   "password" => ""
]);

$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```